# I need to put amount '0' if the row exist but has no amount in my "where " conditions

Tags: plsql

I need to put amount '0' if the row exist but has no amount in my "where "  conditions.

the original command is:

```
select t.aaa, count (t.bbb), sum (t.ccc)
from nrb t
where t.vvv IN  ('3','4','5','6','D','E','F')
  and t.ddd like '50%'
  and t.eee >= TO_DATE('2012/03/21','YYYY/MM/DD')
  and t.eee <= TO_DATE('2012/07/21','YYYY/MM/DD')
group by t.aaa
order by t.aaa
```

and the result is:
"result" tab in excel file.

I need this result:
"result 2" tab in excel file.

the file : I did send full result . 
http://www.mediafire.com/?69cc4ay6cyt9cr9

how can I have this?

Pl/sql 7.0.2 unlimited user license

oci : 9.2

oracle db : 11.1.0.6.0 enterprise

os : win xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
select t1.aaa, coalesce(t2.bbb_count, 0) bbb_count,
    coalesce(t2.ccc_sum, 0) ccc_sum
from (
  select distinct aaa
  from nrb
) t1
left join (
  select t.aaa, count (t.bbb) bbb_count, sum (t.ccc) ccc_sum
  from nrb t
  where t.vvv IN  ('3','4','5','6','D','E','F')
    and t.ddd like '50%'
    and t.eee >= TO_DATE('2012/03/21','YYYY/MM/DD')
    and t.eee <= TO_DATE('2012/07/21','YYYY/MM/DD')
  group by t.aaa
) t2 on t1.aaa = t2.aaa
order by t1.aaa;
```

Comment: ->   new question : 
this query will give me a table with 3 Columns. how can i make a table like excel sheet and loop the " t.ddd like '50%'  " to "  t.ddd like '55%'   ". i  mean i will have 15 Columns with same rows.